# Getting length data from GPX files within QGIS

Tags: qgis, gpx

I just got a Garmin etrex and promptly took it for a hike.  I can get the path and the trackpoints into QGIS with no issue.  However, I cannot figure out how to get the distance between the trackpoints.  I've played with the CRS and the file formats (converting to .shp for example).

When I go into the attribute table and attempt to calculate a new field using $length, all I get are NULL values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to a line, lines have lengths, points do not. You will need a plugin like [Points to Paths](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pointstopaths_v02/) to convert the points to lines and then you can get the [length of the lines.](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2010/10/calculating-line-lengths-and-statistics.html)

Comment: However, user wants to get the lengths of segments. The workflow could be like a) Convert the track from the GPX file into shapefile b) Cut the imported track line into segments c) Compute lengths of the segments.

Comment: It's got to be quicker than measuring between points interactively. Either the whole track, parts or between points just depends on where the line is cut.